# stop condition for emulating "grep -oE" with awk

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I'm trying to emulate GNU `grep -Eo` with a standard `awk` call.

What the man says about the `-o` option is:

> **-o --only-matching**
>
>      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line.

For now I have this code:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

regextract() {
    [ "$#" -ge 2 ] || return 1
    __regextract_ere=$1
    shift
    awk -v FS='^$' -v ERE="$__regextract_ere" '
        {
            while ( match($0,ERE) && RLENGTH > 0 ) {
                print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                $0 = substr($0,RSTART+1)
            }
        }
    ' "$@"
}
```

My question is: In the case that the matching part is `0-length`, do I need to continue trying to match the rest of the line or should I move to the next line (like I already do)? I can't find a sample of input+regex that would need the former but I feel like it might exist. Any idea?

Comment: But what about the escaping of special regex characters? Is it being taken care of caller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a POSIX awk version, which works with `a*` (or any POSIX awk regex):

```
echo abcaaaca |
awk -v regex='a*' '
{
    while (match($0, regex)) {
        if (RLENGTH) print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + (RLENGTH > 0 ? RLENGTH : 1))
        if ($0 == "") break
    }
}'
```

Prints:

```
a
aaa
a
```

POSIX awk and `grep -E` use POSIX extended regular expressions, except that awk allows C escapes (like `\t`) but `grep -E` does not. If you wanted strict compatibility you'd have to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks dan, The core logic of our replies is the same so I'm marking your answer as the accepted one; mine fits more my needs though (OP privilege^^)

Answer (score 3):

If you can consider a `gnu-awk` solution then using `RS` and `RT` may give identical behavior of `grep -Eo`.

```bash
# input data
cat file
FOO:TEST3:11
BAR:TEST2:39
BAZ:TEST0:20
```

Using `grep -Eo`:

```bash
grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+' file
FOO
TEST3
11
BAR
TEST2
39
BAZ
TEST0
20
```

Using `gnu-awk` with `RS` and `RT` using same regex:

```bash
awk -v RS='[[:alnum:]]+' 'RT != "" {print RT}' file
FOO
TEST3
11
BAR
TEST2
39
BAZ
TEST0
20
```

**More examples:**

```bash
grep -Eo '\<[[:digit:]]+' file
11
39
20

awk -v RS='\\<[[:digit:]]+' 'RT != "" {print RT}' file
11
39
20
```

Comment: While it's probably safe to assume that when you have GNU awk available then you should also have access to GNU grep, this is a nice GNU solution, +1

Comment: Indeed but don't attempt to make `gnu-awk` behave like `grep -oP` :-)

Comment: I believe the whole idea is not to use GNU tools.

Comment: @kvantour: But OP started question with `I'm trying to emulate GNU grep -Eo`. If `grep` is `gnu` then `awk` can also be `gnu` IMO

Comment: My understanding is that the user does not have access to GNU grep (eg a bare Sun server) and hence also GNU awk. POSIX grep is missing the '-o' flag which the user might want to mimic. POSIX `awk` seems to be the best option. (but the question might require a bit of updating, to clarify all of this).

Comment: @kvantour you're right, the target systems are Linux, BSD and Solaris. While there is GNU grep on a few of them, I think it's better to write something that'll work on all of them. That said, I don't discriminate against answers that are implementation specific, as they might prove useful at a later date

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the various comments and answers I think that I have a working, robust, and (maybe) efficient code now:

<sub>**tested on AIX/Solaris/FreeBSD/macOS/Linux**</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/sh
  
regextract() {

    [ "$#" -ge 1 ] || return 1
    [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && set -- "$1" -

    awk '
        BEGIN {
            ere = ARGV[1]
            delete ARGV[1]
        }
        {
            tail = $0
            while ( tail != "" && match(tail,ere) ) {
                if (RLENGTH) {
                    print substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                    tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
                } else
                    tail = substr(tail,RSTART+1)
            }
        }
    ' "$@"
}

regextract "$@"
```

**notes:**

- I pass the ERE string along the file arguments so that `awk` doesn't pre-process it (thanks @anubhava for pointing that out); C-style escape sequences will still be translated by the regex engine of `awk` though (thanks @dan for pointing that out).
- <s>Because assigning `$0` does reset the values of all fields,
  I chose `FS = '^$'` for limiting the overhead</s>

  Copying `$0` in a separate variable nullifies the overhead induced by assigning `$0` in the `while` loop (thanks @EdMorton for pointing that out).

###### a few examples:

```bash
# Multiple matches in a single line:
echo XfooXXbarXXX | regextract 'X*'
X
XX
XXX

# Passing the regex string to awk as a parameter versus a file argument:
echo '[a]' | regextract_as_awk_param '\[a]'
a
echo '[a]' | regextract '\[a]'
[a]

# The regex engine of awk translates C-style escape sequences:
printf '%s\n' '\t' | regextract '\t'
printf '%s\n' '\t' | regextract '\\t'
\t
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will malfunction for match which might have zero or more characters, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
1A2A3
```

then

```
grep -Eo A* file.txt
```

gives output

```
A
A
```

your `while`'s condition is `match($0,ERE) && RLENGTH > 0`, in this case former part gives true, but latter gives false as match found is zero-length before first character (`RSTART` was set to `1`), thus body of `while` will be done zero times.